# dict.fromkeys return dictionary in reverse order from a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am adding all the items of a list to a dictionary as keys equal to none.

```
template_vars = headers[1:]
kwargs = dict.fromkeys(template_vars)
```

When I print the values of both variables in the terminal, they are as follows.

```
{'Type': 'Nauman Ahmad', 'Name': 'Cyborg'}
['Name', 'Type']
```

The order of the dict is reversed? How can I get in the same order as of the list `template_vars` because the order matters to me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered. Use a OrderedDict if order is important:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

kwargs=OrderedDict((k, None) for k in template_vars)
```

Comment: Note that you can use `fromkeys` with an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, Dict is never sorted, it actually stores key, value pairs in random order and which are fetched using keys. If you want to maintain the order, then use [OrderdDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.